# Heat series graph: order in gradient bar

Tags: c#, livecharts

I am new to livechart and I have made the following basic graphic in livechart. However, I have 2 doubts about it.

```
 using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using LiveCharts;
    using LiveCharts.Defaults;
    using LiveCharts.Wpf;

    namespace heatmap
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
                var brush = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#000000");
                var r = new Random();
                cartesianChart1.Series.Add(new HeatSeries
                { 
                    Values = new ChartValues<HeatPoint>
                    {

                        new HeatPoint(0, 0, 0.25),
                        new HeatPoint(0, 1, 0.5),
                        new HeatPoint(0, 2, 0.5),
                        new HeatPoint(0, 3, 1),


                        new HeatPoint(1, 0, 0.5),
                        new HeatPoint(1, 1, 0.5),
                        new HeatPoint(1, 2, 1),
                        new HeatPoint(1, 3, 0.5),

                        //"Robyn Williamson"
                        new HeatPoint(2, 0, 0.5),
                        new HeatPoint(2, 1, 1),
                        new HeatPoint(2, 2, 0.5),
                        new HeatPoint(2, 3, 0.5),


                        new HeatPoint(3, 0, 1),
                        new HeatPoint(3, 1, 0.5),
                        new HeatPoint(3, 2, 0.25),
                        new HeatPoint(3, 3, 0.25),



                    },
                    Fill=brush,
                    Stroke=brush,
                    Foreground = brush,
                    FontSize=20,
                    DataLabels = true,
                   // LabelPoint=val=>"hola",
                    //The GradientStopCollection is optional
                    //If you do not set this property, LiveCharts will set a gradient


                    GradientStopCollection = new GradientStopCollection
                    {
                       new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255), 0),
                        new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0), .25),
                        new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(7, 193, 67), .5),
                        new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(0, 128, 0), .75),
                        new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(0, 60, 31), 1),


                    },


                });


                cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(new Axis
                {
                    Position = AxisPosition.RightTop,
                    LabelsRotation = 0,
                    FontSize=15,
                    Labels = new[]
                    {
                        "variable rent",
                        "int tax.",
                        "Real state",
                        "money"
                    },
                    Separator = new Separator { Step = 1 }
                });

                cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(new Axis
                {
                    FontSize = 15,
                    Labels = new[]
                    {
                        "Money",
                        "Real state",
                        "int tax",
                                             "variable rent"


                    }
                });

            }



            }
        }
```

Output:
[image]

1. How can you reverse the order of the gradient bar? 1 in the top and 0.25 in bottom.
2. Is it possible for each HeatPoint to place a tooltip or a color for each label(1 label white and other label yellow)?

thanks to all

Comment: I can't help you with the second question, but for the first question, have you tried editing the stop points when you're creating the list of `GradientStop` items? Each `GradientStop` you create accepts a color and a position from 0 to 1. Try changing that position value for each of the `GradientStop` items while leaving their color the same. You'd start with `new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255), 1), new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0), .75),` and so forth.

Comment: Hi ozeanix, i do it, but the result is the same and no colors in squares.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work @user119144, I'm not too experienced with LiveCharts but hoped the simple suggestion would work. Good luck solving your problem!

Comment: No problem, thx for the The attempt to solve.

Comment: Sadly this is not supported

Comment: okay, thx for the answer c: